# How do I get Visual Studio to apply syntax highlighting to annotated .vb files?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, when I *Annotate* a .vb file with TFS, it is shown without any syntax highlighting.

Here's an example:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried starting Visual Studio in safe mode. Syntax highlighting works fine for regular, non-annotated tabs. It also works fine for annotated C# files.

How can I get syntax highlighting to work with annotated VB files?

Comment: From what I have seen, syntax highlighting isn't supported for VB.NET in the annotated view (while it is for C# and others).

Comment: @AlexWhite hey, you're right - I just tried a .cs file and it worked. Could have sworn I'd tried it already.. Revised question to specify .vb files. It also doesn't work for me with .sql files, but I'll leave that out of the question since it doesn't bother me as much.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015. Syntax highlight disappears when .cs file is annotated. Have to use 3rd party tools.